# Jest --watch runs all tests always

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I recently switched from Mocha to Jest. Everything works fine except the watch mode which always runs all tests (not only tests related to uncommited files as it says in the docs). I've searched the docs and with google but I haven't found any information on this issue.

My jest config is

```
  "jest": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/generated/",
      "/mock/",
      "/tools/",
      "/transactions/"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 90,
        "functions": 90,
        "lines": 90,
        "statements": 90
      }
    },
    "resetMocks": true,
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/tools/setupTest.js"
  },
```

The `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` only contains one row:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
```

Babelrc:

```
 "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "rewire",
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
      ],
      "presets": [
        "es2017",
        "react",
        "stage-0",
        "es2015"
      ]
    }
  }
```

I start the tests with `jest --watch` and it prints the message "Determining test suites to run" but then all tests are run **even when no files are uncommited**.

I'm on windows 7 and I run the command in powershell.  Node version: `v6.9.1`
Jest versions: `"babel-jest": "20.0.3"`, `"jest": "20.0.4"`

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: I never got it to work on that computer. I did switch workplace in October last year so I have another computer now where it works...

Comment: having the same issue with jest

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I'm guessing, but try using testPathIgnorePatterns in addition to coveragePathIgnorePatterns.

Answer (score 0):

You need a git repo to run `jest -o` (`jest --watch` implicitly uses it).

From the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#running-from-the-command-line):

> Run tests related to changed files based on hg/git (uncommitted files):
>
> `jest -o`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jest v27.6.3 and gitbash, not sure if this is a new feature, but you don't have to wait for the all tests to run, you can interrupt it by pressing enter key and it will stop running and ask for input from the user:
[image]